# Electromagnetic Waves frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, gravity, speed-of-light, frequency

Does Gravity affect the frequency of an electromagnetic wave?
If so, does it increases or decreases it? Please explain me. Thank you!

Comment: Read gravitational redshift here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: Pehaps this is interesting for you https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276196/does-the-speed-of-light-change-in-a-gravitational-field/276233#276233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we describe a plane-wave (or a single photon) by its wave vector:

$$ k^{\mu} = (\omega/c, \vec k) $$

what pops out is that the frequency is the time-like part of a 4-vector. We can look at energy and momentum:

$$ p^{\mu} = \hbar k^{\mu} = (E/c, \vec p) $$

to try to find a natural rest frame:

$$ p^{\mu}p_{\mu} = \frac 1 {c^2}[(E)^2-||p||^2c^2] = \frac {\hbar^2} {c^2}[\omega^2 - (ck)^2] = 0 $$

so that there is no rest frame.

Energy is a property of the observer's frame, not the wave. The wave just goes at $c$, locally.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers OP's question

Comment: @KarimChahine Frequency isn't a property of the wave, it depends on the reference frame.

Comment: @JEB - But doesn't a gravitational field blue-shift (or is it red-shift, I always mix them up) EM radiation entering from infinity?

Comment: @honeste_vivere yes, you need 2 reference frames to compare frequencies. You didn't mention infinity in the question.

Comment: @JEB - Ah good point.